# Black Unity default objects for about 5s after WebGL Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Why does the WebGL-Build looks so black(first picture),
after I have started the game. But after I have played for about 5s the black objects look quite normal again.

The canvas on the ground is also not the problem. Because one time I removed it and the problem did remain.

In addition, the MusicVisualizerBlocks(they visualize the music, you know) are missing

But this issues only happen if I export the project to WebGL. 
No Issues on Anrdoid or Windows builds.

You can see the bug live.. if you play this game on itch.io
https://confusingfuturegames.itch.io/musicbump

With Canvas on the ground:

[image]

Without Canvas on the ground

[image]

Android and Windows look:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use the LWRP or [HDRP](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/09/24/the-high-definition-render-pipeline-getting-started-guide-for-artists/) ?

Comment: actually, I use the standard settings..